# Adding JList items line by line into a string arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist, jlist

Im trying to put items from a jList line by line into a ArrayList

This is my theory but the output is not correct. The output is just

[Ljava.awt.Component;@7b066956

```
 StringTokenizer comp = new StringTokenizer(lb_breakdown_components.toString(), ","); 

            if(comp.hasMoreTokens())//check for tokens
                { 
                    textfile.add(comp.nextToken());//adding the data as tokens
                }
```

Comment: Hi, wouldn't it be easier to just make the jList based on an array? That way you don't have to worry about adding or removing anything, its already there.

Comment: The Jlist is populated by a DefaultListModel. If you know a better way to get a DefaultListModel into a string arraylist than what I'm attempting here with the jlist items then please let me know. the DefaultListModel also would have to go into the string array line by line, not just as one long string.

Comment: Are you trying to add selected items to a arraylist or just all the items in the jList at once?

Comment: All items but line by line. Either using the Jlist or the DefaultListmodel.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();      // creates array list, although I preferLinkedLists
List list = jList.getSelectedValuesList();      // gets values from your jList and added it to a list
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {      //  this for-loop adds the values of the list to the array list
    test.add(list.get(i).toString());
}
for(String s : test) {      // this enhanced for-loop proves that the code above works
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This should do what you want it to do :)

Remember to import :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: Error : java.util.list cannot be converted to java.awt.list

Comment: @user3320339 sorry I have no idea how to solve this ):

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `ListModel` from the `JList` and loop through the values, populating your `ArrayList`.

Something like this, where **lb_breakdown_componenents** is the `JList` and **textfile** the destination `ArrayList`

```
  ListModel listModel = lb_breakdown_components.getModel();

  for (int i=0; i<listModel.getSize();i++){
    textfile.add(listModel.getElementAt(i).toString());
  }
```

With Java 7 and generics you might not even need the `toString()` call if the model contains Strings.